# React: How can I call these functions in useEffect conditionally inside my component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch, jsx, use-effect

I'm trying to implement this logic to conditionally fetch from APIs, i made the fetching logic inside useEffect hooks, but I'm not able to call them inside my component.
What would be the correct way to do this.
Or what other way can i do this?

For functions getF1,GetF2,getF3 i have used try-catch block, not shown the whole code for that

```
const myComponent = () => {
  
  const [info, setInfo] = useState([]);
  let venueName;
  let cId;

  useEffect(() => {
    const getTData = async (tid) => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        return response.data;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    const getCC = async (tid) => {
      const t2data = await getTData(tid);
      cId = t2data?.xyz;
      console.log(cId);
    };
    getCC(tid);

    async function getF1() {
        const response = await fetch(url1);
    }

    async function getF2() {
        const response = await fetch(url2);
    }
    async function getF3() {
        const response = await fetch(url3);
    }

    getF1();
  }, []);

  const mainF = () => {
    let res1 = info.filter((x) => x.fields.travelId == tid);
    if (res1.length != 0) {
      linkValue =
        res1[0].a != undefined
          ? res1[0].a
          : res1[0].b != undefined
          ? res1[0].b
          : getF2();
      let res2 = info.filter(
        (x) => x.fields.colorId == cId
      );
      if (res2.length != 0) {
        linkValue =
          res2[0].a != undefined
            ? res2[0].a
            : res2[0].b!= undefined
            ? res2[0].b
            : getF3();
        let res3 = info.filter((x) => x.fields.venue == venueName);
        if (res3.length != 0) {
          linkValue =
            res3[0].a != undefined
              ? res3[0].a
              : "www.google.com";
        }
      }
    }
    return linkValue;
  };

  let finalValue = mainF();
```

Comment: make function out side of useEffect & call then from inside useEffect.

like that useEffect(() => {   getCC(tid);  getF1();   },[])

Also, not sure but i think u need to store venueName, cId in state.

Comment: should i make getF2, getF3 outside useEffect too? I am calling them conditionally inside mainF();

Comment: Yes you can try with that.. otherwise I think it will give compilation error like function not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try with set instance and call with instance that function.

```
const myComponent = () => {
  
  const [info, setInfo] = useState([]);
  let venueName;
  let cId;
  const instance = this;
   
  const getTData = async (tid) => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        return response.data;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    const getCC = async (tid) => {
      const t2data = await getTData(tid);
      cId = t2data?.xyz;
      console.log(cId);
      return cId;
    };
   

    async function getF1() {
        const response = await fetch(url1);
    }

    async function getF2() {
        const response = await fetch(url2);
    }
    async function getF3() {
        const response = await fetch(url3);
    }

  useEffect(() => {
    getCC(tid);
    getF1();
  }, []);

  const mainF = () => {
    let res1 = info.filter((x) => x.fields.travelId == tid);
    if (res1.length != 0) {
      linkValue =
        res1[0].a != undefined
          ? res1[0].a
          : res1[0].b != undefined
          ? res1[0].b
          : instance.getF2();
      let res2 = info.filter(
        (x) => x.fields.colorId == cId
      );
      if (res2.length != 0) {
        linkValue =
          res2[0].a != undefined
            ? res2[0].a
            : res2[0].b!= undefined
            ? res2[0].b
            : instance.getF3();
        let res3 = info.filter((x) => x.fields.venue == venueName);
        if (res3.length != 0) {
          linkValue =
            res3[0].a != undefined
              ? res3[0].a
              : "www.google.com";
        }
      }
    }
    return linkValue;
  };

  let finalValue = mainF();
```

Comment: tried, show "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getF2' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your functions outside or useEffect and then call them inside useEffect conditionally. And you can even keep your useEffect separate for different functions. If you have a separate dependency list for each function.

```
const myComponent = () => {
  
  const [info, setInfo] = useState([]);

const [function1Success, setFunction1Success] = useState(false);
const [function2Success, setFunction2Success] = useState(false);
const [function3Success, setFunction3Success] = useState(false);


  let venueName;
  let cId;

  const function1 = async() => {
        const response = await fetch(url1);
        if (condition to find response is success){
        setFunction1Success(true);
        }
    }

  const function2 = async() => {
        const response = await fetch(url1);
 if (condition to find response is success){
            setFunction2Success(true);
            }
    }

  const function2 = async() => {
        const response = await fetch(url1);
 if (condition to find response is success){
            setFunction3Success(true);
            }
    }


 
// ADD THE BELOW CODE

useEffect(() => {
if(cond)function1();
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
if(cond && function1Success)function2();
}, [function1]) // Here

useEffect(() => {
if(cond && function2Success)function3();
}, [function2]) // Here

  const mainF = () => {
    let res1 = info.filter((x) => x.fields.travelId == tid);
    if (res1.length != 0) {
      linkValue =
        res1[0].a != undefined
          ? res1[0].a
          : res1[0].b != undefined
          ? res1[0].b
          : getF2();
      let res2 = info.filter(
        (x) => x.fields.colorId == cId
      );
      if (res2.length != 0) {
        linkValue =
          res2[0].a != undefined
            ? res2[0].a
            : res2[0].b!= undefined
            ? res2[0].b
            : getF3();
        let res3 = info.filter((x) => x.fields.venue == venueName);
        if (res3.length != 0) {
          linkValue =
            res3[0].a != undefined
              ? res3[0].a
              : "www.google.com";
        }
      }
    }
    return linkValue;
  };

  let finalValue = mainF();
```

### Updated: Call function1 only after function2 is executed successfully and so on..

You can then use separate useEffect for every call. And define state for each function like in the above code `function1Success | function2Success | function3Success`.

If one function is executed and results is success. Then you can update state of that specific function to true. Like if `function1` is success you turn the state of `function1Success` to true.

And since, function1Success is added in the dependency list of useEffect which carries `function2`, function2 will execute next. And so on and on and on.

And we even check, if function1Success is true before executing function2Success.

Comment: My conditions depend upon the results of calling the previous function. Ex:  first i wanna call function1( ) first, if it gives me undefined or empty result, then i call function2( ) to fetch, and so on... in that case how would i do, any suggestions?

Comment: I tried this but it gets into an infinite loop and continuously keeps printing the value of 'finalValue'

Comment: @Aishwariya can you share your code. What you tried?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should call this all function outside of useEffect and then u can use them every where inside your component. And if you only want result from api so instead of return i would suggest you to store inside one state and use them inside component.